# Mistake in Walter Greiner's "Quantum Mechanics" Special chapters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac-delta-distributions, scattering-cross-section, textbook-erratum, fermis-golden-rule

I am going through section 2.4 and 2.5 of Walter Greiner's book "Quantum Mechanics: Special Chapters". In section 2.4, there is a detailed analysis of the elastic scattering of a free electron and a photon. In page 57 of section 2.4 Eq. 2.56 the book mentions that
$$
\frac{\text{Transition prob.}}{\text{Time}} \propto |\langle \vec q_f |e^{i(\vec{k}_i - \vec k_f)\cdot \vec{x}}|\vec q_i \rangle|^2  
$$
In the next line, the matrix element is calculated to be
$$
\langle \vec q_f|e^{i(\vec k_i  - \vec k_f)\cdot \vec{x}}|\vec q_i\rangle = \int d^3 \vec x \frac{e^{-i(\vec q_f+\vec k_f )\cdot \vec x}}{\sqrt{L^3}}\frac{e^{i(\vec q_i +\vec k_i )\cdot \vec x}}{\sqrt{L^3}} = \delta_{\vec q_f  + \vec k_f , \vec q_i +\vec k_i }
$$
However, in page 58 of the next section 2.5, eq. 2.60 the two equations are combined to give:
$$
\text{Total cross section} \propto \frac{\text{Transition prob.}}{\text{time}} \propto \delta_{\vec q_f  + \vec k_f , \vec q_i +\vec k_i }
$$
Shouldn't the delta function in the last equation be squared? What am I missing?

Comment: $\delta_{ab}= \delta^2_{ab}$

Answer (score 1):

Scattering  matrix elements contain energy-momentum conservation enforcing delta functions
$$
\langle k_f|S| k_i\rangle  = (2\pi)^4 i \delta^4(k_f-k_i) T_{fi}.
$$
As the OP correctly says, these should be be squared when going from matrix elements to cross sections.
$$
 \sigma\propto |\langle k_f|S| k_i\rangle |^2  = |(2\pi)^4  \delta^4(k_f-k_i)|^2 |T_{fi}|^2.
$$
What are we to make of the square of the delta function?

Perhaps $f(x)\delta(x) = f(0) \delta (x)$ can help, and so we conjecture that
$$
|(2\pi)^4  \delta^4(k_f-k_i)|^2\stackrel{?}{=}(2\pi^4) \delta^4(0) (2\pi)^4 \delta^4(k_f-k_i). 
$$
We still have to figure out what  what to do with the  $(2\pi)^4 \delta^4(0)$.  However, the Fourier transform formula
$$
\int d^4 x \,e^{ikx} = (2\pi)^4 \delta^4(k)
$$
suggests that  that
$$
(2\pi^4) \delta^4(0)= \int d^4 x
$$ has the physical interpretation as the volume of spacetime i.e the spatial volume of the system  $V$ times the elapsed time $T$ of the experiment.

This "argument" that $\delta(x)^2 = \delta(0) \delta(x)$ clearly nonsense, and the rest is  is hardly rigorous either, but perversely the final result  turns out to be correct. The factor $VT$ is  necessary to get the dimensions of the cross section come out correctly as an area,  and a  proper derivation leads to a  version of Fermi's "golden rule" for the rate of transitions into a continuum of states. If Greiner's  account is to be truly  "detailed" he should have explained this.

You should  find a proper derivation in any book on Particles and fields.

Roughly speaking, the golden rule derivation  goes like this: Time-
dependent perturbation theory generically says that the amplitude to
be in a new state grows linearly with the elapsed time $t$. The probablility
to be in a particular state therefore seems to grow as $t^2$. When we are making transitions to a continuum of levels, however, the energy-time uncertainty principle restricts the range of available energy levels to be inversely proportional to $t$. The net effect is a transition probability to allowed levels that grows linearly with time.